# Gitlab: why "squash" merge creates two commits?

Tags: git, gitlab

To reproduce it:

1. Create issue
2. Open Merge Request (MR) from the issue
3. Make changes with multiple commits
4. Check "squash commits" and Merge the MR

Why on earth this creates TWO commits in history with exactly the same changes?

The commits titles:

1. Merge branch '123-branch-name' into 'dev'
2. Full Issue name

What is the point of that?

Comment: Look into the differences between a merge and a rebase and you'll understand.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sounds like you create one commit containing your changes (commit `Full Issue name`) and a merge commit, merging changes from that commit into `dev` branch.

The merge commit is usually created for every merge request. This can be changed in `Settings`->`Merge Request Settings` by choosing e.g. `Fast Forward Merge` instad of `Merge Commit`. This will lead to only one commit on top of your current `dev` HEAD, which will only work if `dev` can be fast forwarded.

Checking `squash commits` will squash all commits in the feature branch you want to merge *before* merging it. Thus, if you had more than one commit in your feature branch, they would be squashed into one commit, which would be merged, creating a merge commit as you described (as long as your merge request settings are set to `merge commit`, see above).

The point of that is that you might want to see that changes were performed on a different branch. This is done by *not* fast forwarding the branch you merge into, but create a merge request instead. This displays that two lines of development were merged, while a fast forward merge (not creating a merge commit) would not.

Comment: What drawbacks does `Fast Forward Merge` have? Besides the fact that it's indistinguishable from regular commit in `dev` (in my case) branch?

Comment: I wouldn't call it "drawback", but working with fast-forward merges lets your history look as if every commit was performed directly on `dev`, and leads to a linear history with no merges in between. When you also squash, every feature will be a single commit in this linear history. That's just one possible workflow, that does not preserve parallel development history, since you cannot determine which work was done on a different branch. If you work in a project with many developers, a merge workflow might be better suited to see at a glance which features were developed on parallel branches.

Comment: One drawback is you cannot use [Merged Results Pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merged_results_pipelines.html#prerequisites), which might be useful if you wanted to bump version and update changelog upon successful merge (they are working on this though).